# Drywall patching using 3M Patch Plus Primer

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

Whenever I patch a drywall using 3M Patch Plus Primer, it ends up looking bumpy and unnatural. I can't get it to spread evenly and perfectly flat. So I do try sanding after it hardens, but it's really hard to sand and it doesn't come out flat.

I was able to smooth out the top edge shown on the photo, yet after painting, you can still see the boundary between the 3M patch and the normal drywall.

I'd appreciate any tips. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Are you able to get results you like with a different product? It takes a lot of skill to make a patch disappear especially on a wall without texture.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used 3m patch.

I use drywall mud, you have to feather out quite far from the hole you patch so you do not notice the raised area. You apply the mud and sand it down as much as you can without revealing the tape or mesh patch, then feather out more mud to make the raise area very gradual. Sand it all so there is no lines, smooth transition between old wall and new mud, then use a can of spray texture to match the existing wall texture to make it blend in better. Then you prime and paint.

If you search YouTube for how to mud a drywall but-joint you will see what feathering involves.